# How to display UIImage on uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableview` where I display an `UIImage` based on `UISwitch` state. I am storing the switch state in `NSMutableArray`. I am able to display only two images if i try to display more than two its not displaying. If I switch OFF any one of the two earlier `UISwitch` states. The new switch state (which i was trying to display earlier) will get displayed that too only one.

Comment: Indent your code yaar...

Comment: i waited for 5 minutes and then I reformatted... now this looks good :)

Comment: Please specify the data that you are saving and their corresponding event handlers. `selectedSympIPArray = [NSMutableArray array];` by this way you are always creating a fresh array, is this how you really want?

Comment: No when i switch ON two uiswitch then in uitableview where uiswitch is present uiimage is displayed . if i try to switch ON one more uiswitch then the uiswitch which was switched ON last the image gets hidden and for the new uiswitch which was turned ON image appears .`selectedSympIPArray` contains the indexpath for which uiswitch is switched ON

Comment: @raptor, post GUI snapshots !

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming in your tableview each cell represents an instance of a model from an array. Would it not be better to update the model when the switch is toggled?:

```
...
MyObject theObject= [myObjects objectAtIndex:index];
theObject.switchState = TRUE;
[self.tableView reloadData];
...
```

and then reload the tableview cells

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellidentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


     MyObject *thisObject = [myObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if(thisObject.switchState) {
          ... configure cell accordingly
     }

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Marcel...i have updated the code..the image is appearing for two cells if i try to switch ON more cells the image is not appearing for those cells

Comment: Could you post your new code?

Comment: In your code you are not de-queueing or creating a cell, you are also not returning a cell. The method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: needs to create/de-queue a cell, configure it and then return it (see my example code).

Comment: @Marcel.. i didnt post those codes because i wanted to post the exact codes for hiding the image and displaying the image.. i have updated the code with dequeue and return cell.

Comment: Could you try to hardcode all switches on and also try hardcoding all switches off. That way you can see wether it's going wrong in your logic, or in the tablecell's display.